# How to use unique attribute along with encryption in a mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, encryption, mongoose, cryptojs

I have a MongoDB database which I access through NodeJS using Mongoose. I use encryption to store email addresses using the `crypto` module. When retrieving an email address, I decrypt the database value. Here is the relevant part of the Mongoose schema using the encryption getter and setter:

```
...
email: {
  type: Schema.Types.String,
  required: true,
  trim: true,
  unique: true, // <-- this does not work due to encryption
  set: value => this._encryption.encrypt(value),
  get: value => this._encryption.decrypt(value)
},
....
```

As you can see, the field is using the `unique` attribute. But due to the encryption, the encrypted value of the same email address is always different. Now I can store two different users using the same email address and no errors are thrown.

How do I use encryption along with a `unique` field attribute?

Comment: Hi Nicky, MongoDB has two solutions to secure your information. The first is encrypt all of MongoDB’s network traffic. For that, you can use TLS/SSL in your connection. The other option is to use Encryption at rest (Available in MongoDB Enterprise only).

Comment: Hi @JonathanBrizio, thanks for replying. I already use a TLS/SSL connection, this is not a MongoDB feature, but a HTTP protocol. I do not have a MongoDB Enterprise account so I'm not familiar with "Encryption at rest". Storing encrypted data in MongoDB is nothing new, I'm simply looking for a way to verify uniqueness for encrypted data fields. I'll keep looking!

Comment: Hi @Nicky did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest perhaps doing the encryption / setting outside of the schema. The get method will still be fine.

This way you can firstly encrypt the new email coming in.

`const encryptedEmail= _encryption.encrypt(email);`

Then you can do a search to make sure that this hash does not exist:

`const email = await emailSchema.findOne({email: encryptedEmail});`

```
if (!email.length) {
    emailSchema.create({ email: encryptedEmail});
}
```

This is obviously not as clean as doing it within the schema however it would achieve the desired encryption at rest.

Comment: Hi @Jack, thanks for replying. The thing is that the `crypto` module is non-deterministic. Meaning that, everytime I encrypt the (same) string, the encrypted string is always different. This means I can't search for the encrypted string either.

Comment: Could you create a hash of the email when first creating and then search by that?